# stat_ellipse：Just draw a few ellipses

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I just add ellipses to selected clusters?

My dataframe is:

```
                          tSNE_1      tSNE_2                 cell cluster
AAACCTGAGAATGTTG-1_1   0.1299930  37.2503543 AAACCTGAGAATGTTG-1_1       1
AAACCTGAGACTTTCG-1_1 -13.5023528 -27.4902174 AAACCTGAGACTTTCG-1_1       0
AAACCTGAGGATCGCA-1_1  -9.8842112 -19.5328594 AAACCTGAGGATCGCA-1_1       0
AAACCTGAGTGAACGC-1_1   4.3203117 -30.0705565 AAACCTGAGTGAACGC-1_1       4
AAACCTGCACAGTCGC-1_1 -27.8499015 -22.1165523 AAACCTGCACAGTCGC-1_1       0
AAACCTGCACCGAATT-1_1 -20.0805292  -1.2176293 AAACCTGCACCGAATT-1_1       0
AAACCTGCACGAGGTA-1_1 -10.1745982 -18.8803267 AAACCTGCACGAGGTA-1_1       0
AAACCTGCATGCCCGA-1_1 -25.5127833 -28.3838518 AAACCTGCATGCCCGA-1_1       0
AAACCTGCATTAGGCT-1_1 -20.1743971 -15.7444141 AAACCTGCATTAGGCT-1_1       0
AAACCTGGTAAACGCG-1_1   0.1975782 -36.0322037 AAACCTGGTAAACGCG-1_1       4
AAACCTGGTCAGAGGT-1_1   0.7356793 -28.6817771 AAACCTGGTCAGAGGT-1_1       4
AAACCTGGTGGTCTCG-1_1  14.1409199 -25.8666523 AAACCTGGTGGTCTCG-1_1       4
```

And my code is:

```
p=ggplot(dat,aes(x=tSNE_1,y=tSNE_2,color=cluster))+geom_point(size=0.95)
p=p+stat_ellipse(data=dat,aes(x=tSNE_1,y=tSNE_2,fill=cluster,color=cluster),
                 geom = "polygon",alpha=0.2,level=0.9,type="t",linetype =2,show.legend = F)+coord_fixed()
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by converting `cluster` to a `factor`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = tSNE_1, y = tSNE_2, color = factor(cluster))) +
  geom_point(size = 0.95) +
  stat_ellipse(
    data = dat, aes(fill = factor(cluster)),
    geom = "polygon", alpha = 0.2, level = 0.9, type = "t", linetype = 2, show.legend = F
  ) +
  coord_fixed()
#> Too few points to calculate an ellipse
```

[image]

**DATA**

```r
dat <- structure(list(tSNE_1 = c(
  0.129993, -13.5023528, -9.8842112,
  4.3203117, -27.8499015, -20.0805292, -10.1745982, -25.5127833,
  -20.1743971, 0.1975782, 0.7356793, 14.1409199
), tSNE_2 = c(
  37.2503543,
  -27.4902174, -19.5328594, -30.0705565, -22.1165523, -1.2176293,
  -18.8803267, -28.3838518, -15.7444141, -36.0322037, -28.6817771,
  -25.8666523
), cell = c(
  "AAACCTGAGAATGTTG-1_1", "AAACCTGAGACTTTCG-1_1",
  "AAACCTGAGGATCGCA-1_1", "AAACCTGAGTGAACGC-1_1", "AAACCTGCACAGTCGC-1_1",
  "AAACCTGCACCGAATT-1_1", "AAACCTGCACGAGGTA-1_1", "AAACCTGCATGCCCGA-1_1",
  "AAACCTGCATTAGGCT-1_1", "AAACCTGGTAAACGCG-1_1", "AAACCTGGTCAGAGGT-1_1",
  "AAACCTGGTGGTCTCG-1_1"
), cluster = c(
  1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "AAACCTGAGAATGTTG-1_1",
  "AAACCTGAGACTTTCG-1_1", "AAACCTGAGGATCGCA-1_1", "AAACCTGAGTGAACGC-1_1",
  "AAACCTGCACAGTCGC-1_1", "AAACCTGCACCGAATT-1_1", "AAACCTGCACGAGGTA-1_1",
  "AAACCTGCATGCCCGA-1_1", "AAACCTGCATTAGGCT-1_1", "AAACCTGGTAAACGCG-1_1",
  "AAACCTGGTCAGAGGT-1_1", "AAACCTGGTGGTCTCG-1_1"
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I find another way. The stat_ellipse is dispalyed in the coating，so I got rid of unwanted groups，extract subsets，and add ellipse layer by layer.Your method is much simple than mine.My code'code'##extract subset
dat0<-dat[dat$cluster=="0",]   dat1<-dat[dat$cluster=="1",]  dat4<-dat[dat$cluster=="4",]
p=ggplot(dat,aes(x=tSNE_1,y=tSNE_2,color=cluster))+geom_point(size=0.95)
p0=p+stat_ellipse(data=dat0,aes(x=tSNE_1,y=tSNE_2,fill=cluster,color=cluster),
                 geom = "polygon",alpha=0.2,level=0.9,type="t",linetype =2,show.legend = F)+coord_fixed()